# In OS X 10.8.4 what are the standand user accounts that should be in directory utility

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, malware, active-directory

I believe I have some malware or virus on my os x 10.8 computer.

I need to know what the list of user accounts and groups are the ones that come on a standard install of Mountain Lion in the Open Directory Utility.  please can someone help me out with this. I have a whole mess of users and groups that I think should not be there and my ML is doing some crazy things and being accessed remotely and sending information to websites and ftp servers that I have no idea where they are or what they are and files are being modified and it's not by me and I'm the only one who uses or has access to the computer. It seems to be access my computers at work (that are windows 7 computers, they run my POS for my business) I think some malware is remotely getting access to them and taking information from them. Please if someone knows the users and groups that come standard on a fresh install of ML in directory utility please post them for me.  Thank you for anyone who can help me out.

Comment: Have you checked out the Activity Monitor?  You can find it in applications\utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have the same bug I do.  Look under Group and see if you see SMBSID as the name and then S-1-5-32-544 as the value for Administrators. Then see if you see similar additions to other groups. These are windows permissions and have no place on a mac.  When you have admin priviledges and are viewing the groups see if you can enable, disable, or change root user. Mine is grayed out.

This is after a 7x secure erase and reinstall and pulling NO data in.  It's a rootkit of some sort and as long as it has control of the root it can make anything look like anything. apple is working on recovering the root user. Until then, anything you do is useless.